# Best way to combine and minify JS / CSS on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, minify, asset-management

First of all, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778083/why-does-a-rails-app-on-heroku-serve-assets-via-all-css-and-locally-via-individua/1778139#1778139), the `:cache => true` option on `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag` doesn't work on Heroku. Is this true? I've found `:cache => true` to work occasionally, but not always (weird!)

Also, what's the best solution here? Ideally it would seamlessly combine and minify all CSS / JS. [Heroku Asset Packager](http://github.com/amasses/heroku_asset_packager) claims to do this -- are there better options?

Answer (score 23):

I'm using Jammit on Heroku. Works Great. You can locally build your assets and check in to heroku. use

```
jammit --force
```

the current version 0.5.1 has issues working on heroku but you can install the fixed version from git://github.com/documentcloud/jammit.git

If you are using Rails 3, specify the below in your bundler Gemfile:

```
gem "jammit", :git => "git://github.com/documentcloud/jammit.git"
```

For Rails 2.*

```
config.gem "jammit", :source => "git://github.com/documentcloud/jammit.git"
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 8):

I've found that adding a git pre–commit hook which compiles and packs assets, then adds them to the current commit comes in handy in this case.

Mine using Jammit looks something like this (in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`):

```
jammit
rake barista:brew
git add public/assets/*
git add public/javascripts/*
```

Like this all your assets will be packed for you and you don't have to worry anymore about it.

Answer (score 4):

GitHub has a good answer for this, and I'm sure you could modify Heroku's deployment scripts to integrate:

http://github.com/blog/551-optimizing-asset-bundling-and-serving-with-rails

Comment: The Heroku deployment script is `git push heroku`. Not much to modify.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it on heroku yet, but [Sprockets](http://getsprockets.org/) might be good for that.  Also, in the past, I've had more luck with

```
:cache => 'all.css'
:cache => 'all.js'
```

instead of 'true'

Comment: Make sure you check out https://github.com/jeffrydegrande/sprockets_on_heroku if you want to use Sprockets. Sprockets is definitely something to watch, as it will be bundled by default in Rails 3.1 (not sure if it's in Rails 3 yet).

Answer (score 1):

It's a different way to manage your CSS/Javascript but you may want to check out the Rails plugin [shoebox](http://github.com/ddollar/shoebox).

Shoebox can do combining, minifying, and caching.

Answer (score 0):

The project name says it all:

http://github.com/amasses/heroku_asset_packager

Comment: But this puts packaged assets into `/tmp`, which, according to http://docs.heroku.com/constraints, won't necessarily stick around across requests

Comment: Have you tried Jammit?  http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/  I've read several commits from other public projects that have switched to this though I haven't tried myself.  I'll have to test that out myself one day soon... don't opt for pre-compilation, have the gem compile the assets, and then clear out any files from underneath it, and see if it recompiles the assets again.  I haven't read Jammit's source to confirm but it's worth a shot unless you've found something else.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the config options to compress your assets.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#customizing-the-pipeline

```
config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compress = true


gem 'uglifier'
gem 'yui-compressor'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably various ways to do this, but what works for me is to minify before pushing. Then I use a subtree to keep my build files separate from the "source" files. So, for example, if you build to a folder called "dist", you can push to a subtree called heroku/master like this:

```
git subtree push --prefix dist heroku master
```

Just don't forget to ensure that the dist folder is not ignored (it often is, by default) - so edit your .gitignore file accordingly.

The --prefix command ensures that the dist folder effectively becomes the "root" folder from the point of view of that branch.