# Jammit & delayed_job on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

I just added delayed_job to my app on Heroku. Everything was working fine locally but that stopped after pushing to Heroku. The rake job worker appears to be crashing and gives this error for Jammit:

```
==> dj-3625324.log (crash) <==
(in /disk1/home/slugs/352624_647fcb1_cd2f-0ad62d88-55e5-45dd-81ff-560f42525b6e/mnt)
Jammit Warning: Asset compression disabled -- Java unavailable.
rake aborted!
Broken pipe
/disk1/home/slugs/352624_647fcb1_cd2f-0ad62d88-55e5-45dd-81ff-560f42525b6e/mnt/Rakefile:8
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

-----> Your application crashed.

       Examine the backtrace above this message to debug.
```

How do you debug an issue like this to resolve?

Thanks

Comment: Had you pushed to Heroku before? Did you give it a shot with --trace? (heroku rake your:task --trace). Just glanced at Jammit here - looks like it can gracefully degrade if you're using 3.2...

Answer (score 1):

Might want to look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889837/best-way-to-combine-and-minify-js-css-on-heroku) regarding using Jammit on Heroku.