# stylesheet_link_tag(:all) generates reference to `all.css` on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, stylesheet

I have `stylesheet_link_tag(:all)` in my layout.

It behaves as expected on local machine, even when I run it in production environment (`rails s -e production`).

By expected I mean that it emits all the links to existing stylesheets without concating them into `all.css` and it *does not* emit the link to `all.css`.

But when I deploy it to Heroku, the result is the same plus a link to `all.css` in the beginning. This is what I don't want and don't expect, especially when production environment on local machine does not emit it.

So the question is how do I get rid of `all.css` link on Heroku without specifying all files manually?

Thanks.

Comment: You're not using `:cache => true`?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't. Only `stylesheet_link_tag(:all)`

Comment: Could it be that you've got a file called all.css on the server and it's automatically linking to that?

Comment: I don't think so. The request to `all.css` fails with 404. Also my Git repo has no such file and thus could not be possibly deployed to Heroku. If it would be on the file system, then it would also appear on the local machine in all environments (which it doesn't). So I would say No, it can't be that there is such a file.

Comment: I have just double checked from Heroku console: `File.exists? 'public/stylesheets/application.css' # => true` and `File.exists? 'public/stylesheets/all.css' # => false`. 

So definitely there is no such file on the file system.

Comment: I had the same issue, heroku doesnt supports asset storage so this is the source of the problem. I ended up including each css individualy.

Comment: @dombesz Just to be on the same page: What exactly do you mean by "asset storage"?

Comment: @Dmytrii Nagirniak heroku doesnt allow you to upload, or create files from the code. Because their system stores your app in the cloud in different servers, and it's too costly to for them to allow you to create files. And if you do stylesheet_link_tag(:all) it generates an all.css on the fly and heroku doesnt support to store that file on their filesystem, and thats why you get errors. Maybe you can try to add the all.css to the repo and upload to heroku. Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: all.css is only generated with :cach=>true. I don't set it.

Comment: @dombesz - your last comment is spot-on, you should post it as an answer.  I almost missed it because it was hidden under the "fold" which shows the first four or five comments on a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku is doing some special handling of asset files, see for example:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3 and
[Why does a rails app on heroku serve assets via all.css and locally via individual files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778083/why-does-a-rails-app-on-heroku-serve-assets-via-all-css-and-locally-via-individua) especially the final comment about `:cache => true` working now and about `File.open` operations not working.

They aren't expecting your use case as the most common, so it is possible that there is some bug in their handling. I would try explicitly setting `:cache => false` and `:config => false`

Comment: I tried setting `:cache => false` and it has no any effect. I already said that in the comments to my question. The links you provided don't really explain anything, they don't explain WHY `all.css` is generated together with all other files (instead of a single one). Can't see anything in you answer that helps me to solve the issue :(

Comment: You said in your comment that you weren't setting `:cache => true` which is a different thing than explicitly setting `:cache => false`. The links that I provided explain why `File.exists? 'public/stylesheets/all.css'` might return `false` even if a bug in Heroku's code is incorrectly assuming it exists in some code paths.

Comment: Ray, I tried to set `:cache => false` explicitly. Same thing. I also can't see where your links explain the situation with `File.exists?` Can you please point it to me?

Comment: On [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488090/stylesheet-link-tagall-generates-reference-to-all-css-on-heroku/5610329#5610329) August Lilleaas Jan 22 '10 at 21:07 says that using `:cache => true` generates an `all.css`, but that `File.open operations` are blocked.

Comment: My point was that your Mar 31 5:00 comment about `File.exists 'public/stylesheets/all.css'` returning `false` doesn't imply that Heroku isn't failing to respect your `:cache => false` and creating some virtual version of `all.css`.